# Extending a column in the user table in django is not creating a entry in table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have extended the Django user table with a boolean variable.

```
class UserLogin(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    isFresher = models.BooleanField()
```

I have made changes in the admin inline.

```
class LoginInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserLogin
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'loginTable'

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (LoginInline,)
```

I have got the flag in the admin table. When I add a user to the user table I can see the flag. If I check the flag then I can see an entry `True` with `user_id` in the `UserLogin` table. If the flag is not checked then I can not see an entry in the table? How to make this `False` entry into the table?

Comment: seems like you didn't register the models, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#the-register-decorator

Comment: Which class should I register?                                                                                         
Ps:  I am not using `admin.ModelAdmin`, I am using `admin.StackedInline`